# WPF Infragistics control - ContentPane Header not showing multibinding value's

Tags: wpf, infragistics

Infragistics WPF 'ContentPane' control has a header property where we can write the heading text. I want to bind 2 collection's count and some static text to it, but iam unable to get this working.

code:
`<igDock:ContentPane.Header>
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Developer {0}, {1} ">
            <Binding Path="ObCollection1.Count" />
            <Binding Path="ObCollection2.Count" />
</MultiBinding>
</igDock:ContentPane.Header>`

Also, if i do single binding , then this works ok , code is :

`<igDock:ContentPane Background="Transparent" CloseButtonVisibility="Hidden" Header="{Binding DeveloperColl.Count, Mode=OneWay}" >`

Plz help friends..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The issue was with using StringFormat, we have to use ConverterParameter instead of the StringFormat for this particular Infragistics control to get this thing to work :)